# was writing vs had been writing

Tags: past-perfect, past-continuous

If someone died before he finished writing a book, and he had spent two years on it, which tense should I use:

> 1. He was writing the/a book for two years before he died.
> 2. He had been writing the/a book for two years before he died.

I think the second one is correct, but I'm not sure about the first one.  Is past continuous tense compatible with a duration for-phrase？
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are possible, but (2) would be better with 'when he died'.

Comment: @kate Bunting,  May I ask if they mean the same thing if they're both possible?  I think 2 expresses the intended meaning, whereas 1  means he set aside two years for writing and he died in that progress,  but it doesn't say how long he had spent in writing.

Comment: They mean the same to me. 'He was writing the book for two years' _does_ imply that the writing was in progress for all of those two years (whether or not he was working continuously).

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Sorry to bother again, but I'm still a little confused.  Is sentence(1) correct because of the presence of "before"？  According to what I have learned，the formulation "was doing... for... " is not correct on its own.  For example, don't say  " He was working for eight hours yesterday"，but we can say " He worked for it hours yesterday"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with _He was working for eight hours yesterday_. Sentence (1) means that he spent the two years before his death with the book in progress. _He wrote the book for two years_ would be unidiomatic; it sounds as though he spent the whole time writing non-stop!

Comment: I may need some time to digest. Thank you for your time and patience.